# pegionhole with assumptions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> In a jar of 115 balls, each being red or blue. There are 60 red balls.
>   Show that there are at least two red balls in the jar exactly 4 terms apart.

**My Approach**

There are 115 balls and we need 4 terms apart, so we make groups of 6

$115 \over6$$ = 19.167$

also we know we have 60 red balls 
$\therefore$ $60 \over6$$ = 10$

Since we have 2 possibilities, red or blue from pigeon holes principle, we can say that red and blue both have
 $115 \over(6*2)$$= $$115 \over12$  which is approximately  $9.583$ , which means that out of red and blue, one has $10$ pairs and the other has $9$.

Also we know that there are 10 pairs red balls.

This shows that it is true that the red balls have 10 pairs of 6 balls which are red. This also shows that in the pair of 6 balls, the first and the last is also red and they are 4 terms apart in turn proving the hypothesis.

**I am not sure if I did it right as this seems too sketchy**

Comment: I have no idea what your terminolgy $\frac {115}{6=19.167}$ or $\frac {60}{6=60}$ or $\frac {115}{6*2}$ means to you.  "we can say that red and blue boy have $\frac {115}{6*2}$ is utterly incomprehensible.   "which means out of red and blue" (out of red and blue what), one has (one what) 10 pairs (what does "having" a "pair" mean) and one (again one of what) has (what does has mean).  Also we know there are 10 pairs red balls.  Um, if there are 60 red balls that is 30 pairs.  Then "10 pairs of 6 balls"....  Okay, I have no fricking idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I had written it with wrong math jax, I have fixed it now though. out of red and blue **balls** what I did, was made each coloured of ball to be a hole and the the pair of 6 balls to be the pigeons. Also I meant that we make pairs of 6 balls, rather than pairs of 2. more like groups of 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem rather sketchy ... in fact, I can't follow it at all. Groups of $4$? red and blue? Pair of $6$ balls?

Also, the question itself is weird: balls in a jar ... 4 terms apart?

OK, I assume that the question basically is: If you pick $60$ numbers from $1$ through $115$, then there must be two numbers with a difference of $4$

Here's why:

Pick $60$ numbers.

Divide them into $4$ groups, depending on whether the number $\equiv 0,1,2$, or $3 \bmod 4$

Note that in each group, the numbers are a multiple of $4$ apart.

So, if you have a group with at least $16$ numbers, then for no two of them to be exactly $4$ apart, they need to be at elast $8$ apart, but that means the lowest and highest number are at least $8 \cdot 15 =120$ apart, which is impossible.

So, all $4$ groups have exactly $15$ members. But now you have a problem with the group of numbers that are $\equiv 0 \bmod 4$, for the lowest possible number is $4$, and the highest needs to be at least $8 \cdot 14=112$ higher, which is $116$, and so there must be at least two that are exactly $4$ apart.

Comment: Sorry but I got completely lost after the dividing in 4 groups part. Also it is supposed to be groups of 6 (made a mistake in typing) I took group of 6 as the first and last term int he group of 6 will be 4 terms apart.

Comment: @AgentSmith I mean if two numbers have the same remainder when divided by $4$, put them in the same group. For example, $15$ and $31$ would go into the same group, since the remainder when dividing by $4$ is $3$ in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, that clears the part of dividing them in 4 groups, but "So, if you have a group with at least 16 numbers, then for no two of them to be exactly 4 apart, they need to be at elast 8 apart, but that means the lowest and highest number are at least 8⋅15=120 apart, which is impossible." I did no get this part either?! Sorry but I am just confused a lot as to what you mean there.

Comment: @AgentSmith OK, let's look at the group whose remainder is $1$. What numbers can end up in this group?  Well, you have $1,5,9,13,17,...,113$.  Now, in order for no two of them to be exactly $4$ apart, the best we can do is to get the numbers $1,9,17,25,...$, i.e. they'd need to be $8$ apart (at least).  OK, but if you have $16$ numbers, then the last one is $15$ times $8$ removed from $1$, which is $121$ .. but the numbers only go up to $115$. So, it's impossible to not have $2$ numbers that are exactly $4$ apart. And this holds for any of the groups, if they have at least $16$ members.

Comment: OHHH, I see, so we are kind of proving it with contradiction, when we say that let's assume that there are no two numbers that are 4 apart, and so we look at 8 apart, but when we see it as 8 apart there is a contradiction as the last term is over 115 am I going on the right track???

Comment: @AgentSmith Yes, that's exactly it!  Put differently: if you're trying *not* to get balls $4$ apart, then the 'holes' are $8$ apart, but the group with remainder $0$ has only $14$ holes, and the other three groups have $15$ holes, for a total of $59$ holes.

Comment: ohhh right, it makes complete sense now!!! Thanks a lot!!!!! I was trying to solve it by thinking too narrow but this explained better thanks.